# FaceBook C# SDK in .NET 2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using facebook registration plugin . Signed request that is sent to other page I need to extract data from it. I am having hardtime using Facebook C# SDK cause it starts with .NET 3.5 version while I am having a .NET 2.0 application.It shows all errors about assemblies.Is there any simple function I can include instead of using this whole SDK and complicating things more than I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook C# SDK requires minimum of .net 3.5. .net 2.0 is not supported and will not be supported in future versions. The only way would be to update the framework to .net 3.5

Comment: Hmmm . had to implement functions I needed 2.0 way instead.Thanks.